# Knockout break foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

For the below code when the if condition is satisfied I need to break the loop.

I read [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) documentation, but did not find a way to break this.

```
<li>
    <!-- ko foreach: $parents[2].productData -->
       <!-- ko if: repositoryId == $parent.productId -->
           <a data-bind="ccLink: {route: '/'+$parent.productId}"><img data-bind="attr:{src: mediumImageURLs[0]}" /></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
       <!-- /ko  -->
 </li>
```

Comment: Why do you need to break a foreach loop within markup? That seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should filter your array to only the elements you intend to render first and then foreach over those.

Comment: You must be thinking of `ko foreach` as a regular `for` loop, but it isn't meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't break a `ko foreach`, but you can bypass each iteration based on a condition passed to `if` binding. Just pass the condition for your loop to break to the `if` binding.

Here is an example on breaking the `foreach` if the value is greater than 3.

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.contents = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```css
p{
  background: gray;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <div data-bind="foreach: contents">
    <!--ko if: $data < 4 -->
      <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @Ray in the comment, This might seem to work but could cause performance issues if the array is very large. Technically, the `foreach` iterates for every element in the array, only the HTML is not rendered.

Comment: Although this does achieve the requirement, keep in mind that the foreach isn't actual breaking. The HTML simply isn't rendering but the `foreach` keeps going till it reaches the end of the array. When arrays are large this can become a performance issue.

Comment: @Ray Yeah! it might cause a performance issue if the array is large. Thanks for pointing out. I was just trying to address the OP's problem here.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid performance issue use slice

```
<div data-bind="foreach: contents.slice(0, 20)">
```